# knockout increment variable inside html

Tags: knockout.js

Well i have two foreach :

```
 <div data-bind="foreach : parent"> //parent count :5
    <div data-bind="foreach: child"> // all children count  together is 40
    <div data-bind="text : counter"  class="target"> </div>
   </div>
</div
```

parent has 5 or 8 or x children, and children sum is 40.
What i want to achive is that  .target text should be  from 1 to 40:

```
<div class="target"> 1 </div>
<div class="target"> 2 </div>
...
<div class="target">40 </div>
```

How to do that?

Comment: You probably want to use `$index`. See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-2-using-index-parent-and-other-context-properties

Comment: I know about $index,  in this case need what i said exactly

Comment: What you ask for does not make sense. The foreach will immediately iterate through all of them. You can iterate through all of them in your code. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i have two foreach, parent and child. parent has 5 variables and  all child  together has 40. inside child foreach i want to numerate text. from 1-40.

Comment: Edit your question to say what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okey i figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is done a couple of ways. The first is a bit more solid, as it actually counts up to find the number of the item you're on based on indexes.

The second is more like you originally asked for: something that just increments each time through the inner loop. It is "less solid" because if you used it for another run-through of the data, it would just keep counting up from where it left off.

```js
var foo = 1;
vm = {
  increment: function() {
    return foo++;
  },
  counter: function(parentIndex, childIndex) {
    var result = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < parentIndex; ++i) {
      result += vm.parent[i].child.length;
    }
    result += childIndex;
    return result;
  },
  parent: [{
    child: [-1, -2, -3]
  }, {
    child: [-4, -5]
  }, {
    child: [-6, -7, -8, -9]
  }]
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach : parent">
  <div data-bind="foreach: child">
    <div data-bind="text : $root.counter($parentContext.$index(), $index())" class="target"></div>
  </div>
</div>
Or
<div data-bind="foreach : parent">
  <div data-bind="foreach: child">
    <div data-bind="text : $root.increment()" class="target"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```